# Winform ListView databind

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, data-binding

I have a Listview that uses databind. I set the DataSource property to a binding source. All works fine. The problem is that I need to have a column that is not databinded and contains only buttons that have the same handler for click event. To accomplish this I tried to add a subitem that is a button for each ListViewItem after InitializeComponent but doesn't work, nothing is displayed. Also I set the list view column type to Control.
If I add elements to ListView and isn't databinded that the buttons appear.

So it will be a great help for me to know if buttons could be displayed in column that is not databinded when the listview uses databinding for rest of columns.

Thanks!

Comment: ListView or ListBox?  They are two different things (and I think you mean ListBox because the ListView doesn't have databinging in WinForms).

Comment: List view it correct, sorry :(

Comment: You **can't** mean ListView, because ListView doesn't have a DataSource property!?!

Comment: The control list view from visual web gui so I've maked the assumption that also the original winform control has this property also. After that I've found that listview from winforms doesn't have this property :(. It seems that is property is implemented just in this third party control.

Comment: @Neil Barnwell, databinging is the new hotness

Answer (score 1):

The best thing to do here (assuming you mean [ListBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.aspx)), is to have a single button above or below the listbox, that uses the `ListBox.SelectedItem` property to investigate the selected item and do something with it.

Comment: I appreciate that, but it's not typical design.  On a website you might expect to see a *hyperlink* in a column, but on a Windows UI users expect either to double-click an item in a listbox or select an item then press a button (or both).  It makes for a much less cluttered interface.